# Incompatible types when assigning types and invalid operands to binary

Tags: c, function

I'm working on what I thought would be simple but I have ran into some issues I can't seem to solve. The issues revolve around the resitance_current function in the code. The two error message I receive are:

1) incompatible types when assigning to type 'float *' from type 'float'

2) invalid operands to binary / (have 'float' and 'float *')

I'm trying to use the function resitance_current to calculate resistance and current. to do this I pass the values of "length" of wire "area_circle" of wire and "voltage" and by using the resistivity formula to find R:

R = ρ L / A

and ohms law to find I

V = R * I

I can't seem to resolve why the float types are clashing. I have to keep the one resitance_current function to calculate resistance and current so help with passing the float pointers and resolving the current issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help ;)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float areaOfcircle(float radius_circle)
{
    float area_circle;
    area_circle = M_PI * radius_circle * radius_circle;

    return area_circle;
}
void resitance_current(float length, float area_circle, float voltage, float* resistance, float* current)
{
    float resistivity;
    printf("%f %f %f", length, area_circle, voltage);
    resistivity = 1.782*exp(-8);
    resistance = ((resistivity*length)/area_circle);
    current = (voltage/resistance);
}
int main()
{
    float radius, voltage, length, current, resistance;

    // take radius as input
    printf("Enter the radius of wire : ");
    scanf("%f", &radius);
    if (radius < 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the Voltage of circuit : ");
        scanf("%f", &voltage);
        if (voltage < 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter the Length of Wire : ");
            scanf("%f", &length);
            if (length < 0)
            {
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Cross Sectional Area of Wire : %.2f", areaOfcircle(radius));
                resitance_current(length, areaOfcircle(radius), voltage, &resistance, &current);
                printf("Resistance = %f , Current = %f", resistance, current);
                printf("\n");
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lookup "pointer" and "dereference operator `*`" in whatever tutorial/text you're using.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a pointer argument to a function, as you do with `float *resistance` and `float *current`, you also have to dereference it when you're assigning to it as an l-value or accessing the pointed-to value:

```
*resistance = ((resistivity*length) / area_circle);
*current = (voltage / *resistance);
```

Do note that I put a space between the division operator `/` and the dereference operator `*` to prevent the compiler from seeing a multiline comment start.